# Why something redirects HTTP to HTTPS in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having a problem with Elastic Beanstalk, at AWS.

It seems all right, the log files say that my app is ok and running, but it can't be found by the browser.

In middle way, I don't know why, the request changes to HTTPS, and the ELB is not allowing HTTPS, I don't have a SSL Certificate yet. But it is all configured to HTTP.

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

---

My config: ruby 2.1.4 Passenger

Comment: any chance you can share the url that redirects? basically you need to find out if it's the elb or nginx or passenger that redirects the https

Comment: Tal, it was a huge and shame mistake. Thanks for your replay. I was sure that I had commented the config.forcessl at rails environment file, but I did it just for test environment and forgot to do the same for production. This small mistake cost me three weeks, the worst three weeks in my professional life. I have never had a problem that take me so much time. But, thank you for mind.